# Unable to perform db.savechanges

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

MyDbContext.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ExploreCalifornia.Models
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        //constructor
        //takes name of the database OR database connection string
        public MyDbContext() : base("ExploreCalifornia")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Tour> Tours { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TourController.cs

```
// POST: /Tour/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Tour tour)
        {
            try
            {
                //insert into db 
                db.Tours.Add(tour);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Error trace:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException' in EntityFramework.dll
```

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ExploreCalifornia-20140217103953.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ExploreCalifornia-20140217103953;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I am starting out on ASP.NET MVC 5. I am unable to create a record and insert into the db. By right, MyDbContext should create a DB if it does not exist. When the code reaches, `db.savechanges()`, it throws `InvalidOperationException`. I could not find out what the reason is.

Added Web.config.

Comment: Show us your web.config, particularly the connection string and EF section.

Comment: @DavidG added for your reference

Answer (score 0):

In `web.config <connectionStrings>` `<add name="DefaultConnection"` should be `<add name="ExploreCalifornia"`

You should also check to make sure the database has also actually been created.

Comment: I am using the method called Code-First Development. Do I need to ensure beforehand that the database has been created ?

Comment: it also returns an error "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<TResult>.ToString" timed out

Comment: It depends how it's been set up - try the change to the connection string name, rebuild, refresh a page and then look inside the App_Data folder (having clicked "show all files" in the submenu above in VS) and see if your db aspnet-ExploreCalifornia-20140217103953.mdf is there

Comment: Tried your solution but App_Data is still empty

Comment: There are many things that could be the source of the problem. Try typing "update-database" in the Package Manager Console, rebuilt, refresh page and inspect App_Data (with show all files), otherwise I would recommend going through [this Microsot tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to get going. Don't assume it's straightforward beyond copying what is said just because it's the first in the series.